# Why does this c-code get a segmentation fault in strcpy?

Tags: c

Why does this code at the strcpy() give me a segmentation fault?  I am using GNU and when the code reaches the strcpy it fails for a segmentation fault.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<assert.h>

void PrintString(char *buff);
int main()
{
    char *buffPtr = malloc(128);

    assert(&buffPtr != NULL);

    memset(&buffPtr, 0, sizeof(buffPtr));

    strcpy(buffPtr,  "This is my string");

    free(buffPtr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `assert(&buffPtr != NULL); memset(&buffPtr, 0, sizeof(buffPtr));` should be `assert(buffPtr != NULL); memset(buffPtr, 0, 128);`. Also Need `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: Because you destroyed your pointer value with that `memset`. You clobbered it with zeros. After that doing `strcpy` to invalid memory location triggered that segfault.

Comment: this `sizeof(buffPtr)` is not returning the value that you thik

Answer (score 5):

The `memset` will overwrite the pointer instead of the memory it points to. It should be:

```
memset(buffPtr, 0, 128);
```

I removed the ampersand and set the correct size (`sizeof(buffPtr)` is the size of a pointer, not the size that was allocated).

You should also change the assert to check `buffPtr != NULL` without the ampersand (`&buffPtr` will never be null). And using `assert` isn't really correct here because it may do nothing in a release build.